# Finding permitted attributes for a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumeration

I'm familiar with the `attributes` method but what I'd like to do is only return the attributes that were permitted in my model's controller.

```
#users_controller.rb
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :birthday, :email)
end
```

What I'd like to do is create an enumerator that excludes unnecessary attributes like ids, timestamps and just include what was written in the example method above:

```
# show.html.erb
<% @user.user_params.each do |key, value| %>
  <p><b><%= key.titleize %>:</b> <%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be:

```
<% @user.attributes.slice('email', 'name', 'birthday').each do |key, value| %>
  <p><b><%= key.titleize %>:</b> <%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

Also, you can make a method in your *user.rb*:

```
def user_params
  self.attributes.slice('email', 'name', 'birthday')
end
```

Now you can do:

```
<% @user.user_params.each do |key, value| %>
  <p><b><%= key.titleize %>:</b> <%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also worth noting that you'd want to `titleize` key or you'll end up returning underscore for multiword attributes. See updated code in my question.

Comment: Yeah. Have to wait a few more minutes to accept. Thanks!